# MS Word automation: can't enable red underlines for spelling check

Tags: c#, vba, automation, ms-word

My code needs to enable spelling check in MS Word 2010 so user can see red underlines under misspellings.

In current version I try to do this to enable spelling check:

```
wordApplication.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = true;
wordApplication.Options.SuggestSpellingCorrections = true;
wordApplication.ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = true;
wordApplication.ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling();
```

I open Word and type in "Test texxt string". After this I run my code but nothing happens:
[image: No underlines under texxt word]

I don't see any underlines under "texxt". If I go to options I see that "check spelling as you type" option was enabled:
[image]

Now if I check this property:

```
wordApplication.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors[0].Text
```

It will contain "texxt" which means that spelling was actually checked.

Also if I simply restart MS Word and type in same text - red underlines become visible:
[image]

I also tried to call Application.ScreenRefresh and set ScreenUpdating properties but this haven't given any effect.

**Note:** I run this code/macro in the beginning, when there is no text in a document. If some text is there - it works.

**Note2:** Exact steps to reproduce:

1. Start MS Word. Go to options and disable "check spelling as you type". Restart Word.
2. Start Word and run following macro:

   ```
   Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = true
   Options.SuggestSpellingCorrections = true
   ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = true
   ```
3. Type in following text: "Test texxt string.". Press Enter.
4. Run following macro

   MsgBox ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors(1).Text

You will see "texxt" in MessageBox but not red underlines

Comment: Is this VBA? VBA doesn't use semicolons at the end of the lines, and the last line wouldn't include the parentheses. When I make those changes and run those lines of code, texxt is underlined and a Spelling dialog box pops up asking me about changing it. When you run your code you get no errors?

Comment: That is C#. But I have same problems with VBA. It works only if document contains some text but if it is empty and this macros is run on the beginning when I start typing soemthing - I don't see any red underlines.

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because I can't really reproduce what you're getting. However, I did find that after running your macro Word would still autocorrect simple errors. I added the line 
    Application.AutoCorrect.ReplaceTextFromSpellingChecker = False
 which caused the red lines to appear.

Comment: You should find after your code has run that the 'as you type' check will not happen until you make a change to the document.  You may also need to wait as it is a background job.  It is not related to the `CheckSpellings` call so will not affect the display.

Comment: @Christina, manipulating with AutoCorrect.ReplaceTextFromSpellingChecker haven't helped me

Comment: @JamesSnell, of course I add some text to document but I don't see red underlines anyway (but if I use Application.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors array I see that spelling check was done)

Comment: Already found a solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Oleg - well found! Can you post is as an answer instead of editing the question, you deserve some rep for finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accident found following solution: if after user typed in some text I call following code underlines are shown:

```
int iDummy = wordDocument.wordApp.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count;
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that you need to execute this code each time after new text is added.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment on Oleg's answer due to low rep, but it's worth noting here that, with **Word 2013**, using the `Application.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count` method seems to remove the current selection for some unfathomable reason, which could be problematic.

A hack to hide this effect by only checking the `Count` when no text is currently selected; e.g.:

```
// "document" is a Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document
var selected = document.Application.Selection.Range;
if(Math.Abs(selected.End - selected.Start) == 0)
{
    var count = document.Application.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count;
}
```